# Updating a list in SharePoint framework - SPFx WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I have followed [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package) and [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/provision-sharepoint-assets) in order to create lists and columns within SharePoint Online. Everything seems to work fine when creating them for the first time. But when I try to modify an existing column within an existing list using *elements-v2.xml*, after redeploying the app in my app catalogue then updating the existing app, the modified columns haven't been updated.

The only thing that works successfully after updating my *elements-v2.xml* is creating new lists and creating new columns within existing lists.

My *elements.xml*, *schema.xml* and *package-solution.json* are the same as in the tutorial in the first link.

Within *elements-v2.xml* I have:

(I want to add an additional choice on line 24)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance
FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"
Title="New List"
Description="New list provisioned from v2"
TemplateType="100"
Url="Lists/NewList">
  </ListInstance>

<Field ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}"
        Name="SPFxCostCenter"
        DisplayName="Cost Center"
        Type="Choice"
        Required="FALSE"
        Group="SPFx Columns">
    <CHOICES>
    <CHOICE>Administration</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Information</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Facilities</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Operations</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Sales</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Marketing</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>New Choice</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
</Field>

</Elements>
```

Within my *upgrade-actions-v2.xml* I have:

```
<ApplyElementManifests>
  <ElementManifest Location="4d9c0146-1219-986c-8d4e-984b42efd732\elements-v2.xml" />
</ApplyElementManifests>

<AddContentTypeField 
     ContentTypeId="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" 
     FieldId="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}" 
     PushDown="TRUE" />
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can modify an existing column using spfx?

Answer (score 0):

I've had sporadic success using the XML based provisioning to create/update assets from SPFx component installs & upgrades.

FWIW, Microsoft has said for many years the best way to provision isn't to use the Feature framework (ie: XML), rather use the API (ie: REST). That's what I recommend & do now...

After installing the component, the first time it's used it does a check to see "is everything as I expect it". In your scenario, that would be "is the column present that I expect."

If not, the web part shows a friendly "error" with guidance to open the tool pane. That explains the situation, tells someone with valid permissions to use click a button in the toolpane that makes the change via REST).

Yes, it's a bit more work, but (1) it's debuggable whereas when XML provisioning doesn't work, it's just a black box with zero logs/errors) and (2) its reliable.